# Can't access Localhost over a network

Tags: networking, xampp, localhost

I am trying to figure out how to access localhost over a network. I am using XAMPP. for my server. When I go to another computer on the network and enter the default gateway I ge the msg The serverhttp://192.168.1.1:80 requires a username and password the server says: WRT54G and then an input box for the Username. I know it's dangerous but I never set up a username or password for the network and just trying to bypass by pressing enter doesn't work. I I use just localhost:85 on my own computer I get the network but this doesn't work for the other computers, they look for their own localhost.

Answer (score 2):

localhost only applies to the machine that you're accessing it from. So when you try going to `localhost:85` it will point to the machine you're on and nothing else.

When you try going to `http://192.168.1.1:80` I'd say you're actually trying to access your router rather than your computer. That's why it says "WRT54G".

What you need to do is find the IP address of your computer within the network. It will look a lot like `192.168.1.1` but the last 1 will be a different number. If you're on windows you can type in `ipconfig` in a command prompt to find your IP address, and if you're on mac you can use `ifconfig`

Once you've got that, then you should be able to access your machine from another computer in the network by typing the IP address. You will possibly need to configure your computer to allow incoming connections on port 80 (or whatever port you want) though to allow it.

Comment: Well I got that far on the other computer I typed in 192.168.1.1(the ip of my computer) on the other computer but got stuck at the username/password thing. As I said above, I didn't set a username/password so I can't figure where it's coming from

Comment: UPDATE: I had the wrong ip address. when i typed in 192.168.1.1 it defaulted to port 80 no matter what I put in. I put the right one for the adapter and the correct port and it worked like a champ!

Comment: can you help me @PaReeOhNos ? I can't access my localhost from the IP which I get from the `ipconfig` command from another device. Let's say android phone, but I can access the ip from my computer. Can you give some clue so I can fix this.

Comment: @RadityaKurnianto make sure the other device is on the same network as the computer. That IP address is purely an internal network address, not available outside of your network. If it already is, then make sure the firewall on the computer allows connections on the required port, otherwise it may be rejecting them